# Docker Desktop is unable to detect a Hypervisor

Tags: docker, containers, virtualization, docker-desktop

When I try to open docker desktop I get this message.

[image]

Docker Desktop is unable to detect a Hypervisor
Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS.

In task manager > Performance tab I see virtualization is enabled.

I have enabled virtualization in BIOS. I have AMD processor and windows 10 enterprice.
In the terminal I can use `docker -v`. Docker version is 23.0.5.
Windows subsystem for linux is enabled, Hyper V is disabled.

Comment: Pretty sure that you either need to go into Docker Desktop settings and tell it to use WSL, then restart, or enable HyperV

Answer (score 4):

have you ever tried to use command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

in powershell (administrator) ?

If so, then you have to search for `turn windows features on or off` in your local computer to turn `hyper-v hypervisor` to `on`.

If you can't turn it on, you have to go to `BIOS` to enable `Virtualization Technology` under system configuration tab.

After tjat you can try to enable `hyper-v hypervisor` again under `turn windows features on or off`.

You can restart your PC after that. And please ensure that Windows Subsystem for Linux is enabled.

Comment: This helped. What I did was:

1) Ran as admin 

'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto'

2) rebooted

3) Ran as Docker Desktop as admin

Answer (score 2):

Check the task manager and check the CPU to detect that virtualization is activated, if it is disabled, enter the BIOS and activate it.
[image: Task Manager Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable `Hyper-V`. You can do so by pasting the code below in an elevated Command Line platform i.e Powershell (Admin) or CMD (Admin).
Here's a quick way of accessing that. `Win + X` then choose Powershell(admin)

Paste this line of code therein :- `dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All`

Reboot your computer to apply the changes, by accepting using the y entry when the prompt comes.

```
#docker `windows` `hypervisor`
```